Unable use Read Aloud on local pdf documents
Last few days, MS Edge is unable to Read Aloud on pdf documents. It works on web page. The progress bar just keeps moving. Any way to solve this problem?


What have you tried to fix this? Have you rebooted? Tried to update Edge (on Settings>About)?

@DrMoishePippik, I tried updating browser and restarting machine. It didn't help. More likely this some network blocking. However, it doesn't give an error.

I checked this on my personal laptop and issue can be still reproduced. So does not appear to be company network issue.
